# How to get coredump with the lack of disk space on RedHat Linux

Tags: linux, core-dump, abrt

I wounder is it possible to compress core dump on the fly and still use default system for processing core dumps in Red Hat Linux (abrt).

Environment description:
Our key daemon crashed when it occupied about 20 GB of RAM and because server doesn't have much disk space to spare there is for the max size of coredump just for 3 GB.

Comment: This would be hilariously slow, but you could perhaps mount a remote filesystem (e.g. via NFS) and send the dump there.

Comment: Our servers are united in cluster so when one of daemons is down its server go out of the cluster.